# Numpy import/install error

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I am fairly new to python and am trying to use libraries like matplotlib. The problem is, they never work because numpy always has some problem. I have uninstalled and installled and done many other things but to no avail. What does this error message mean?

```
ImportError: 
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try `git clean -xdf` (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.

Original error was: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

I am using Windows 10 64 bit, Python 3.6 and i just did pip install matplotlib and pip install numpy, not sure which versions.

Comment: "you are trying to import a failed build of numpy" translates into not having a matching version of numpy and your library that uses it (in this case probably matplotlib). You may also have the wrong version of numpy altogether. This could be having a 32 bit numpy on a 64 bit python or similar. There is however no possible way to help you here because there is no information about your versions and OS in the question.

Comment: Which package manager at you using? pip? Anaconda? Other?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the post to include everything @ImportanceOfBeingErnest

Answer (score 0):

numpy on windows can be a bit of a pain... Our friends at UC Irvine have made this a little easier by pre-building windows wheels which you can download and run
    pip install downloaded_file

You can download the wheels [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs).  Just double check that you also have 64bit Python installed.  If so you can download *numpy‑1.13.1+mkl‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl* and *matplotlib‑2.0.2‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl* for Python 3.6 64 bit. e.g.

```
pip install numpy‑1.13.1+mkl‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl
pip install matplotlib‑2.0.2‑cp36‑cp36m‑win_amd64.whl
```